# Mutiple composable styles for a tikz node using "append after command"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to build a little drawing library in which each node will have the same base, but can be annotated with various options which will cause extra things to be drawn in/on the node.  I'm currently trying to do this by using append after commands for the styles I want, but combining multiple styles each having an append after gives me the error:

```
ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named  is known.
```

Here is an example.  I'd like node (d) to be both crossed out and have the red box.  (The actual drawing doesn't matter, just how to combine multiple styles is my question):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    main/.style={
      circle, minimum size=6mm, very thick,draw
    },
    crossed out/.style={
      append after command={
        node [
          fit=(\tikzlastnode),
          draw=red,
          thick,
          inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
          cross out
        ] {}
      }
    },
    red box/.style={
      append after command={
        node [
          fit=(\tikzlastnode),
          fill=red,
          text width=2mm,
          inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
          rectangle
        ] {}
      }
    }
}

\node [main] (a) {A};
\node [main,crossed out,right of = a] (b) {B};
\node [main,red box,right of = b] (c) {C};

% this one doesn't work
\node [main,red box,crossed out,right of = c] (d) {D};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!  I'm obviously open to a totally different approach for achieving "composable" styles like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to record the name on the node to something else and use that name in the later styles. But you might use `pic`s instead for less headache and more flexibility (in TikZ v3.0).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    main/.style={circle, minimum size=6mm, very thick,draw,keep name},
    keep name/.style={prefix after command={\pgfextra{\let\fixname\tikzlastnode}}},
    crossed out/.style={
      append after command={
        node [
          fit=(\fixname) ,
          draw=red,
          thick,
          inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
          cross out
        ] {}
      }
    },
    red box/.style={
      append after command={
        node [
          fit=(\fixname) ,
          fill=red,
          text width=2mm,
          inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
          rectangle
        ] {}
      }
    }
}
\node [main] (a) {A};
\node [main,crossed out,right of = a] (b) {B};
\node [main,red box,right of = b] (c) {C};
\node [main,red box,crossed out,right of = c] (d) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. May I ask you to add to your answer the `pic` approach, please?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's really not that different. Instead of a node you place a pic but I think we still need to record the main node name. But I find handling pics much easier compared to adding additional nodes. For this particular example a label approach can also be beneficial to eliminate the append after command stuff.